# Loadtesting in burst mode in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am running my load test for a duration of 1 hour,in between the test I want a scenario to run for a duration of 1 minutes at regular interval of 15 minutes.

In jmeter,currently I am able to simulate for all the others scenarios except for the burst mode.
How do I keep the delay for 15 minutes and trigger the request for duration of 1 min? 
How do I achieve the TPS for the burst? Currently I have to manually trigger jmeter script.

Comment: Just use the [Ultimate Threat-Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/#Ultimate-Thread-Group) and model your threats at your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest doing the following:

1. Add a separate Thread Group.
2. Configure ramp-up and thread count as required.
3. Add a [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer), set Thread Delay to 900 000 (15 minutes = 900 seconds, 1 second = 1000 ms)
4. Add a [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller), set Runtime to 60.
5. Add a [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller), set Loop Count to Forever.
6. Place your burst test logic under the Loop Controller.
7. If you need to define requests per second rate during spikes use [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)

Comment: Thanks this worked for me!!! @DmitriT, please do you think you could give your opinion here? http://goo.gl/3eZLml

Comment: I have several of these Thread Groups configured as you instructed, and have Runtime Controller, a.k.a. duration, set to 120 sec, however, I can see that the thread group's HTTP request is executed only one round (with let's say, 80 users) to simulate the burst. The Loop Controller is set to run forever. My assumption was that each thread group would launch 80 requests for the duration of 2 full mins, over & over again, but it only executes 80 requests once, then no more till next cycle. I've the steps w/ the same order as above: Thread Group has (3)->(4)->(5)->(my request). Using JMeter 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I came here since I had the same issue or similar issue of "simulating" burst like request during the load test. I tried to follow the accepted answer but didn't get it to work (perhaps I misunderstood some steps), anyway; I based my solution in @esteveavi comment [Loadtesting in burst mode in Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739846/loadtesting-in-burst-mode-in-jmeter#comment92426396_25739846) from the original post above. And ended up using JMeter's "Ultimate Threat-Group" plugin with something like the following test plan set up:

[image: first thread group having a constant TPS]

[image: second thread group having bursts starting at different times]