# How can I set up JMeter for periodic load test?

Tags: jmeter

I am struggling to simulate 10 users per second doing GET requests for 20 seconds in every 40 seconds and this test should run for 2 minutes.

I used a Thread group where I created 10 threads (users) and ramp-up time 1 second, so the 10 threads are going to be loaded in a second and the loop count is 1.

The following elements were added to this thread group.

Then I added a Constant Throughput Timer with the set up of 60, which means that approximately 10 GET request will happen per second.

Added an HTTP request Sampler for the GET request.

Added a Runtime Controller with the set up of 20 seconds.

Added a Constant Timer with the set up of 40 seconds.

This is just not working out. any help much appreciated.

I checked many websites already but could not find anything which would deal with this 'periodic load testing intervals'.

Comment: Added an answer using throughput timers, but it was incorrect I soon realized :/

Comment: Check out this answer, it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739846/loadtesting-in-burst-mode-in-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

As per Cagy79 pointed out, here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739846/loadtesting-in-burst-mode-in-jmeter)
which actually i have checked already before but had no luck. Just now I was able to make it work:

1. Create a Thread Group with the set up of 200 users, 20 seconds ramp-up, loop count 1 (so 10 user will make GET requests per second for 20 seconds)
2. Create a Constant Timer with the set up of 40000 milliseconds (so the above burst will run at regular interval of 40 seconds)
3. Create a Loop Controller with the set up of Loop Count 2 (so our the burst will run twice, at 40th seconds and 80th seconds only. We do not want it to start to run at 120 seconds)
4. Create the HTTP GET request under (nested) the Loop Controller